# Length mismatching in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on an analysis script in python and I added a couple of lines to check that I wasn't mismatching row numbers and I wrote this

```
smallest_Val = min(len(InputDataFrame),len(Output_Data_set))
print(smallest_Val)
print(len(Output_Data_set.loc[0:smallest_Val, 'Time']))
print(len(InputDataFrame.loc[0:smallest_Val, 'Time']))
```

The output I got makes zero sense to me

```
69841
69842  <-------
69841
```

What on earth is going on here?! I've run this a dozen times and I keep getting the same off by one value. I've added a kludgy workaround to deal with, but the "why" is much more concerning to me.

For additional info, Output_Data_set is 100k rows, created using

```
zero_data = np.zeros(shape=(100000,len(Full_Names)))
Output_Data_set = pd.DataFrame(zero_data, columns=Full_Names)
```

And, InputDataFrame is created by reading in a CSV (the CSV file is a mess)

```
InputDataFrame = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[(6*run+1),(6*run+2),(6*run+3),(6*run+4),(6*run+5),(6*run+6)], header=24)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code? Please provide a [mcve]. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have one possible explanation. I think the misunderstanding comes from the difference between numpy arrays, Python or df.loc.

Smallest_Val is 69841, and let's assume this  is the len(InputDataFrame)

If you try how the len(df.loc[0:10]) behaves on a simple pandas dataframe, it is inclusive, so it will return 11 rows, given that it has at least 11 rows.

For the larger dataframe (output_data_set) it does exactly that.
For the smaller, because it has exactly, 69841 rows, it just returns the total amount of rows, because it can't select more. So it just returns the whole dataframe.

The workaround then would be just to subtract 1 from Smallest_Val.

Comment: BAH!! ...yes that is 100% it. 400 lines of code and it's the definition of "first" and "last" that trips me up